# Share variables instances with embedded Tomcat Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

How can  I access static variables declared outside embedded tomcat Servlet **Context**.
To clarify my problem, below is a snippet of my code:

```java
public class Main{
    static List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    public static void main(String[] args){
      list.add(new Object());//  size==1 
      tomcat = new Tomcat();
      tomcat.setPort(8080);  
      try {
          tomcat.start();
          tomcat.getServer().await();
      } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
      }        
    }

}
//
@WebServlet(
        name = "servlet name",
        urlPatterns = {"/test"}
)
public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("LIST SIZE: " + Main.list.size());// size==0, supposed to be 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible: classloaders are probably not the same...

Comment: @Matthieu Can I add the launcher classloader to tomcat before starting?

Comment: if you are adding the web app dynamically and if its only Strings, you can probably use the Context object

Comment: Do you really start your application via the Main class? And not as a deployed web app in a stand alone Tomcat?

Comment: @vanje yes, I am integrating Tomcat in an existed desktop application, so I need to share data between servlet and others application class instances

Comment: Yes, but this was not my question. Maybe you accidently start your application inside the IDE as a web application (which has usually no own main class but is deployed to a development Tomcat). This would explain the behaviour that you can access the static field in your Main class but it was not initialized, because your Main.main() was never executed in this setting.

Comment: Smells a lot like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. The proper solution _might_ be to move commonly used resources into areas of code that can be used by both, rather than using what you already have unchanged.

Comment: @vanje I am using org.apache.tomcat.embed, which is meant to be started dynamically from your application, so it could be a main functions or any others thread from the existed application

Comment: @OlafKock , I can use file system to store data (string), and share it between servlet and others thread, but how can I share java objects and class instances, is it possible ?

Comment: This should be possible. What says the debugger? If you set a breakpoint in main() the debugger will tell you the Main.list's object ID. Then at a breakpoint in your servlet the object ID of Main.list should be the same. If yes then some other part of the code might change the list. If no, then it might be a classpath problem.

Comment: @vanje I have already test that, and they are different.

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340137/3080094